# Facebook development: No image picker despite multiple "og:image" tags and no debug errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get Facebook to show its image picker tool when a user shares a page that has multiple image choices.

I have multiple og:image meta tags defined. The site runs on http. The images are both > 200px x 200px.

I'm starting to wonder if this is just no longer available in 2016? I can't find anything anywhere on their docs site about the image picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I discovered facebooks debugger is not showing the image picker, but the image picker shows on facebook.